# "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS" counter giving incorrect value in the Combiner, when used in the reducer the value is Zero

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am trying to get the total count of the words in the file so that i could calculate the percentage of each word. I wanted to accomplish this in a single map reduce task.

Tried using the "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS" counter in the combiner function and reducer function. But the results are incorrect. Please find my code below:

Reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  for (Text val : values) {
    String str[] = (val.toString()).split(" ");
    count += Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    sum += Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
  }
  result.set(sum+" "+count);
  System.out.println("All value "+context.getConfiguration().getLong("All",0));
  context.write(key, result);
  System.out.println("Setup value "+context.getCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter",  "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue());
}
```

Result i get here is some number which has no connection with the total count:

Output:

Setup value 0
Setup value 0
Setup value 0
Setup value 0

Expected value:  Map output records=50338

Combiner:

```
public static class IntSumCombiner
     extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
  private Text result = new Text();

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                     Context context
                     ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (Text val : values) {
      String str[] = (val.toString()).split(" ");
      count += Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
      sum += Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    }

    result.set(count+" "+sum);
    context.write(key, result);
    System.out.println("Setup value"+context.getCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter","MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue());
  }
}
```

Output:

Setup value 14296
Setup value 14296
Setup value 14296
Setup value 14296

Expected value:  Map output records=50338

Comment: Can you paste all counters? Also it will be better to paste the entire code, mapper, reducer, job configuration etc.

Comment: Please find all counter values here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B1OxN_MonYU51dN9gfhH27V_FDVWwzzfI7ah-Smmxnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link to the code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bLons8Lf8ya29JZjRNRlFldjg

Comment: Please give the access to google drive, I have requested for it

Comment: Are you able to access it now?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer for the details.